# Different ways to run a local Apache, Java, and PHP local server?

Tags: java, php, apache, tomcat

I need a set up Apache, PHP, and Java (JSP) on my home computer for homework assignments in one of my programming classes.  Our professor gave us instructions for setting up a localhost Tomcat server but I'm not a big fan of it and I was looking for alternatives.  Are there any other server environments that I can use?

I'm using Windows but if you know of something for another OS please list it for others.

Comment: Try XAMPP, its control panel makes it very easy to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to download the Apache HTTP server to run Apache Tomcat applications, you can download [Tomcat here](http://znt.me/apache-tomcat). There's a simple all-in-one PHP Web Server called [QuickPHP here](http://znt.me/quickphp).

Hope that helps, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you on?

I'm not clear that this is exactly what you want, but what I would do is download MAMP or WAMP (depending on your OS; free), which are super simple to set up. Then you could install Eclipse (also free) which will run the java for you.